# missing value when passing dictionary in json format

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I want to pass dictionary list to my web service.
Now I get my data serialized as follow (in json format):

```
{
   "properties":[
      {
         "hobby":[
            "singing",
            "swimming"
         ]
      },
      {
         "hobby":[
            "singing",
            "football",
            "basketball"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "userId":[
      "120",
      "121"
   ]
}
```

And my service is like :

```
void uploadUserProperty(Dictionary<string, string[]>[] properties,string[] userId);
```

When debugging, I find the `userId` is right, but properties have no key.
Can anyone explain something about this?

Comment: What seams to be the problem here? What format does your service take? The serialization of your parameters is correct. What you have there is a list of dictionaries. Can you give as an example of how the data should look like?

Comment: yes,i want to pass a list of dictionary, before pass it is correct, after pass,the value in dictionary is missing

Comment: Your dictionary has a `key` ("hobby") and a `value`. The `value` in your case is a list of strings `string[]` which is correctly parsed as an JSON array as `["singing", "football", "basketball"]`. That's the value of your dictionary and as I see it, it's not missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate entries with key `hobby`, Dictionary has to have unique keys. Also your JSON is representing array data, not the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You declare your `properties` as an array of dictionary objects: `Dictionary<string, string[]>[] properties`. And array (or even a list) is just an enumeration (though less strict, since you can have the same object multiple times). That means that you do not need to uniquely identify  each item and therefore do not require an ID.

Comment: i don't know what you mean

Comment: I mean that the end result depicts exactly your input. There's nothing wrong with the JSON.

Comment: yes,i also thing the json is right. But i don't know why i can get the value in my webservice...but the userId is right, only dictionary has some problem...

Comment: I don't really understand what this dictionary problem is. If you can explain it better or provide an example on how the data should look, maybe we can be of more service to you.

Comment: In the case above, i pass to dictionary array to my web service.of course i want to deal with the dictionary. but when i debug, i found the dictionary contains no key, which is not same with the data i pass. The data i pass contains key "hobby" and value like "swimming", but i can't get these in my web service

Comment: It can be a deserialization problem. Do you have the same data type in your service method?

Comment: both wrote in c#. you mean if i use dictionary, then those language doesn't have dictionary can't use the service? can similar data type(like map in c++) be ok?